# VIM - How to select multiple lines that are not adjacent?

Tags: cursor-movement, visual-mode, visual-block

If you have the following text:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

You can hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> on line 1 and hit <kbd>j</kbd> to select line 2. However, I want to select both line 1 and line 3, but not line 2.

Or, select multiple arears like this:
[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: this is not possible in Vim.

Comment: Not sure what your final goal is, but Iselect may help. It lets you select lines and output them to a file. I have just found it and [describe its basic usage here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611027).

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `V` to do a **line-wise** visual selection? `<C-v>` does a **block-wise** visual selection.

Comment: What is your actual goal (post-selection)? `:global/1\|3/` will let you run an action on only those two lines...

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 4):

From `:h visual-use` (emphasis mine):

> Using Visual mode consists of three parts:
>
> 1. Mark the start of the text with "v", "V" or CTRL-V.
>    The character under the cursor will be used as the start.
> 2. Move to the end of the text.
>    The text from the start of the Visual mode **up to and including the
>    character under the cursor is highlighted**.
> 3. Type an operator command.
>    The highlighted characters will be operated upon.

You cannot exclude certain portions. Visual mode will select **all** of the text between the start and end of the selection. The only caveat is that block-wise visual mode will select a rectangle of text, rather than line by line up to and including the cursor.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using vim on `vscode`, you can hold the `option/alt` key and click on the other line, it will put a cursor there, then you can `shift + v` it.

Comment: Welcome to this site, you can check [the help center](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to have a better idea of what is on topic on this website. What you describe is a behavior of VS Code which doesn't exists in Vim so we usually don't mention them here. Thank you for participating anyway and I hope to see your future contributions on other questions :)